# How to add condition to StreamBuilder's rebuild in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I am using `StreamBuilder` to dynamically refresh UI.

```dart
StreamBuilder<State>( //
          stream: stateStream,
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<BlocState> snapshot) =>
              // do anything
        );
```

When there is new data in the `stateStream`, UI will be refreshed automatically.

However, sometimes the value of new data and old data may be the same. At this time, there is no need to refresh.

How do I control `StreamBuilder` not to refresh this time?

Comment: see https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Stream/distinct.html

Comment: sure, your welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58813226/how-to-add-condition-to-streambuilders-rebuild-in-flutter/58988499#comment103905509_58813226) shows, `distinct` solves my problem

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any type of State management? i.e. Bloc?

If you don't want the widget to refresh... you should add the logic in the Bloc and not in the StreamBuilder. Basically if the data is the same, do not send add any data to the Sink.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the [bloc_library](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/gettingstarted). One of its advantages is that it does not send data to UI if it has not changed. I have recently written [blog post](https://www.netguru.com/codestories/flutter-bloc) where among others I have addressed this functionality.